# Remove specific dates from array

Tags: javascript

I got an array, which contains dates (formatted as dates, not strings) within a specified range:

```
var dates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

var startDate = new Date("2019-04-01");
var endDate = new Date("2019-04-26");

var dates = dates(startDate, endDate);
```

Then I filtered out the weekends like this:

```
var workingDays = dates.filter(function(e, index){  
  return (e.getDay() != 0 && e.getDay() != 6);
});
```

That worked perfectly so far, but my problem is that I need to filter out holidays aswell. I tried to use the same filter function as for the weekends, like this:

```
var holidays = [new Date("2019-04-19"), new Date("2019-04-22")];

var workingDays = dates.filter(function(e, index){
  return (e.getDay() != 0 && e.getDay() != 6 && e != holidays);
});
```

That didn't work tho and just returned the same array as before.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this and just filter out the specified dates in the variable?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we cannot compare two Date objects, we can compare instead their *ms* timestamp counterparts like:

```
!holidays.some(d => +d === +e)
```

where `+d` and `+e` is a shorthand for `new Date().getTime()`

Example:

```js
var dates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

var startDate = new Date("2019-04-01");
var endDate = new Date("2019-04-26");
var dates = dates(startDate, endDate);
var holidays = [new Date("2019-04-19"), new Date("2019-04-22")];

var workingDays = dates.filter(function(e, index){
  return (e.getDay() != 0 && e.getDay() != 6 && !holidays.some(d => +d === +e));
});

console.log(workingDays)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Short and clean! Thanks alot, that's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var holidays = [new Date("2019-04-19").toString(), new Date("2019-04-22").toString()];
var dates = [new Date("2019-04-19"), new Date("2019-04-22"), new Date("2019-01-21")];

var workingDays = dates.filter(function(e, index){
  return (e.getDay() != 0 && e.getDay() != 6 && holidays.indexOf(e.toString()) === -1);
});

console.log(workingDays)
```

Since dates are objects we need some unique property we can check them on. In this case you could try the following. But I am sure there are some more optimized and elegant solutions

Answer (score 1):

Change `e != holidays` to `!holidays.some( x => +x=== +e )`

Explanation: `+x` is shortcut for call `x.getTime()` for compare dates timestamp.

```js
var dates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
      currentDate = startDate,
      addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
      };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
  return dates;
};

var startDate = new Date("2019-04-01");
var endDate = new Date("2019-04-26");

var dates = dates(startDate, endDate);


var holidays = [new Date("2019-04-19"), new Date("2019-04-22")];

var workingDays = dates.filter(function(e, index){
  return (e.getDay() != 0 && e.getDay() != 6 && !holidays.some(x=>+x===+e));
});

console.log(workingDays);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That's working, but Roko was first I guess. That's why I accepted his answer. +1 tho :)